# labels U, V, and W. Which positive, negative and ground?

Tags: electrical

I have a Chinese solar powered pool pump that arrived with leads to the motor with labels U, V, and W. Any idea with would be positive, negative and ground?

Comment: Sounds like the phases of an induction motor.

Comment: Did it not come with a wiring diagram? If so, please post a scan or even a photo of it. It is most likely a 3-phase motor and cannot be wired from DC (positive, negative and ground as you called it) or single phase AC (live, neutral and ground / earth as you probably intended).

Comment: UVW is the std designations for a 3 phase motor.   what were you expecting?

Comment: did you get the 3 phase inverter to drive the motor?

Answer (score 2):

U, V, and W =/= positive, negative, and ground. It's not even line, neutral, and ground (which would be more likely in AC - there is no positive and negative in AC). Instead it's more like line, line, and line. They refer to three phases which have a potential voltage difference from phase to phase. You get your power by connecting the load between the phases. It sounds like you cannot run your motor unless you have a 3-phase power source.